# no return from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote this script based on information I read here on Stack.  It calls data from an API and is supposed to convert the directional degrees to cardinal.   When I run it, I get no output.  There is no error when I inspect the page.  I found no syntax errors when I ran it through Fiddle.

I thought I could simply substitute a number (I tried 45) for num and get the script to run to no avail so I could use an expert eye.  Thank you.

```js
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.stormglass.io/v1/weather/point?lat=40.370181&lng=-73.934193&key=...",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings)
.fail(function(a,b,c) { console.log(a.responseJSON) })
.done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);

  variconwndr24 = function degToCompass(num) {
    var num = response.hours[17].windDirection[1].value;;
    while (num < 0) num += 360;
    while (num >= 360) num -= 360;
    val = Math.round((num - 11.25) / 22.5);
    arr = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE",
      "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"
    ];
    return arr[Math.abs(val)];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?  Is the request being sent?  What is its response status code?

Comment: When I hit that endpoint I get `{"errors":{"key":"API quota exceeded"},"meta":{"dailyQuota":50,"requestCount":51}}`

Comment: May have been a mistake to publish your API key to the entire world...

Comment: I made a snippet and added `.fail(function(a,b,c) { console.log(a.responseJSON) })` it tells you all you need to know

Comment: Note that you're taking an argument named `num`, then immediately creating a new variable named `num` equal to something else... You're also not calling `variconwndr24` anywhere.

Comment: Are you using variconwndr24 outside of your done fn?

Comment: @Amy No errors in the console, yes request is being sent and returning the object.

Comment: @j08691 I just checked and my daily (i'm in my trial period so I'm limited to 50/day) limit has been reached BUT the script was not functioning prior to reaching the limit.

Comment: @HereticMonkey.  doesn't matter.  The trial period expires in 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, try something like this instead:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://api.stormglass.io/v1/weather/point?lat=40.370181&lng=-73.934193&key=xdvfd",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  var degrees = response.hours[17].windDirection[1].value;
  variconwndr24 = degToCompass(degrees);
  console.log(variconwndr24);
  return variconwndr24;
});

function degToCompass(num) {
    while (num < 0) num += 360;
    while (num >= 360) num -= 360;
    val = Math.round((num - 11.25) / 22.5);
    arr = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE",
      "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"
    ];
    console.log(arr[Math.abs(val)]);
    return arr[Math.abs(val)];
  }
```

In the way you did it, degToCompass never actually gets called, and the `num` argument becomes redundant because you immediately redefine it.

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much for your time and clarification!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Just for the record, I'm fairly sure `while (num >= 360) num -= 360;` is equivalent (but possibly worse performance) to `num = num % 360;` Check out this [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u6d3hbor/)

Comment: Thanks @TKoL for the help so far.  I ran the script and was able to get the console log for both the  inconwndr24 and arr [Math.abs(val)].   When calling the data to the html page, is it better to call the var or arr?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but hopefully this answer is relevant: leave the `degToCompass` function alone: it takes a number, does some calculations, and returns another number, so don't do anything inside that function. Just use the result that gets returned from the function.

Comment: sorry about the confusion.  I was referring to getting the variable iconwnndr24 to the HTML page.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, @TKoL.  I was trying to describe getting the variable `iconwndr24` to the HTML page with `$("iconwndr24").append(iconwndr24);` but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: if you have a div in your html like `<div id="iconwndr24"></div>`, then in jquery you can do `$("#iconwndr24").text(iconwndr24);`. That sets the internal text of that div to that variable

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in the callback function for done. You're defining a function `degToCompass`, but that function is never called. Additionally, you're re-defining a parameter for the function that you passed. No point in passing num as a parameter if you just overwrite it. Instead just pass response's desired value as the parameter. Also, for the sake of readability and maintenance, try breaking this up like this :

```js
const arr = [
  "N", 
  "NNE", 
  "NE", 
  "ENE", 
  "E", 
  "ESE", 
  "SE",
  "SSE", 
  "S", 
  "SSW", 
  "SW", 
  "WSW", 
  "W", 
  "WNW", 
  "NW", 
  "NNW"
];

var settings = 
{
  "url": "https://api.stormglass.io/v1/weather/point?lat=40.370181&lng=-73.934193&key=...",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

function degToCompass(num) 
{
    while (num < 0) 
    {
      num += 360;
    }
      
    while (num >= 360) 
    {
      num -= 360;
    }

    val = Math.round((num - 11.25) / 22.5);
    return arr[Math.abs(val)];
}

function faiureCallback(a, b, c)
{
    console.log(a.responseJSON);
}

function doneCallback(response)
{
  // Do some stuff
  var num = response.hours[17].windDirection[1].value;;
  return degToCompass(num)
}

$.ajax(settings)
  .fail(faiureCallback)
  .done(doneCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  I really appreciate it.